# XSLT - accessing elements within a collection

Tags: xml, xslt, collections, sitemap, saxon

I'm attempting to merge multiple XML files within a directory('output') into one single file in a different directory('combine').  The xml files are pretty simple sitemaps:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
       <url>
          <loc>https://blahblah.com/blah</loc>
          <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
       </url>
       <url>
          <loc>https://blahblah.com/blah/blah</loc>
          <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
       </url>
</urlset>
```

I can successfully use Collection() to retrieve the contents of the files, but I cannot seem to access any elements within those files once they are in the collection.

My XSLT looks like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template name="main">
<xsl:variable name="collection" select="collection('output?recurse=yes;select=*.xml')/*"/>
<xsl:variable name="loc" select="distinct-values($collection/urlset/url/loc)"/>
  <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
  <xsl:for-each select="$loc">
 <url>
    <loc>  
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </loc>
    </url>  
   </xsl:for-each>
  </urlset>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That currently outputs..not very much.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd"/>
```

If I change the `<xsl:for-each select="$loc">` to be `<xsl:for-each select="$collection">` it does output the contents of each file, so I know it can access the collection.  However if I try to access any elements directly within the collection files, whether that's via the `distinct-values` above, or via a variety of different references(see below), it just does not show anything.

I've tried:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$collection/urlset/url/loc">
 <url>
    <loc>  
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </loc>
    </url>  
   </xsl:for-each>
```

and

```
<xsl:for-each select="$collection">
 <url>
    <loc>  
   <xsl:value-of select="urlset/url/loc"/>
    </loc>
    </url>  
   </xsl:for-each>
```

and

```
<xsl:for-each select="$loc">
 <url>
    <loc>  
   <xsl:value-of select="($collection/urlset/url[loc=current()])"/>
    </loc>
    </url>  
   </xsl:for-each>
```

and nothing works, except outputting everything from the collection which at least shows the files can be accessed:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$collection">
 <url>
    <loc>  
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </loc>
    </url>  
   </xsl:for-each>
```

If it helps, heres the saxon command I'm using:

```
java -jar c:\saxon\SaxonHE9-9-1-5J\saxon9he.jar -o:C:\Code\photo.old\xml\sitemap\combine\output.xml -xsl:C:\Code\photo.old\xml\sitemap\combine_s.xslt -it:main
```

**Edit -solved!**
Combination of two things:

1. Martin's response below : you need to have the xpath-default-namespace set to the namespace in the source files: `xpath-default-namespace="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"`
2. The collection variable did not work with the distinct-values for whatever reason. I needed to define and access the collection directly within the distinct-values command:  `<xsl:variable name="loc" select="distinct-values(collection('output?strip-space=yes;select=*.xml')/urlset/url/loc)"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, if you have the elements in the namespace `xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"` you want to use `xpath-default-namespace="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"` in the XSLT. Otherwise your paths like `urlset/url/loc` will select elements of those names in no namespace.

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you for you response. Unfortunately adding that into my XSLT didn't have any effect with any of the referencing in the XSLT.

`<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">`

Comment: It seems to do the job in a simplified example at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxDiMBB, I don't see anything else in your snippets that need a correction.

Comment: Thanks Martin,   this get's even more curious..  If i remove the collection element and just run the saxon command on  a specified individual file, it works fine! However as soon as the collection is re-introduced, the elements cannot be accessed again.  Very strange indeed!

Comment: ..and just like that solved!  Looks like for whatever reason, it didn't like the collection variable being used in such a way.   Removing the $collection variable entirely from the XSLT worked.   
`xsl:variable name="loc" select="distinct-values(collection('output?strip-space=yes;select=*.xml')/urlset/url/loc)"/>`

Thank you Martin! It was a combination of your first response (needing the xpath-default-namespace) combined with removing the collection variable and using the collection directly in the distinct-values path.